# Python/Tornado - time.sleep() executed before requesthandler.write()

Tags: python, debugging, tornado

Code:

```
self.write("<html><head></head>"+
    <body><h1>You are now logged out.</h1></body></html>")
sleep(1)
```

The content of `self.write()` will be printed after 1 second, which is not what I want. I want the content printed to the screen first. Why does `sleep()` execute first and how can I make `self.write` execute first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic HTML session?

- Open connection
- Request data
- Get data from server
- close connection
- show the user the data recieved

It's in this order that everything runs.
And since the connection won't close until the `sleep()` is done, you won't see the data.

Comment: You have enlightened me! Thanks!